# Django ModelForm doesn't ingest derived form data correctly

Tags: django-forms, wagtail

I'm having trouble getting a file upload/processing process to work, as part of a Wagtail CMS app I've been developing. I've only been working on the site on and off over the last six weeks but so far I've had quite a bit of success setting up a multilevel page model structure, new block types in streamfields, and ingesting images from an external cloud environment into the Wagtail Image store.

My aim is to have a model that lists a series of Paths (ie. lat/long sequences), the information for which is extracted from files that are uploaded via the Wagtail admin interface. The approach I've taken so far is to build it around Wagtail ModelAdmin so that I can maintain the path list (list, edit, delete) and override the add/create function so that the path files can be uploaded via drag-and-drop; the code for that has been derived from Wagtail's image and document admin apps.

Specifically, I'm finding the values of the fields in the model are not being set when using a model form. These values are derived from the contents of the uploaded file rather than directly from a POSTed form. Because the model values are not being set, saving the model and subsequent editing are affected.

Here are the simplified code snippets:

models.py:

```
from django.db import models

class AbstractPath(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, null=False)
    start_location = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=False, null=False)
    start_timestamp = models.DateTimeField(blank=False, null=False)
    stop_location = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=False, null=False)
    stop_timestamp = models.DateTimeField(blank=False, null=False)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class RealPath(AbstractPath):
    average_speed = models.FloatField(blank=False, null=False)
    max_speed = models.FloatField(blank=False, null=False)
```

forms.py:

```
from wagtail.admin.forms import WagtailAdminModelForm
from wagtail.admin.edit_handlers import BaseFormEditHandler

class PathForm(WagtailAdminModelForm):
    permission_policy = paths_permission_policy

    class Meta:
        model = RealPath
        fields = '__all__'

class PathFormEditHandler(BaseFormEditHandler):
    base_form_class = PathForm
```

admin.py:

```
from wagtail.contrib.modeladmin.options import ModelAdmin, modeladmin_register
from wagtail.contrib.modeladmin.views import CreateView, EditView

from django.template.loader import render_to_string
from django.http import HttpResponseBadRequest, JsonResponse
from django.utils.encoding import force_str

class RealPathCreateView(CreateView):
    def get_template_names(self):
        return ['RealPath_create.html']

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if not request.is_ajax():
            return HttpResponseBadRequest("Cannot POST to this view without AJAX")

        if not request.FILES:
            return HttpResponseBadRequest("Must upload a file")

        # Get dict with data derived from the file - keys align with model fields
        path_form_data = pathfile_process(request.FILES['files[]'])

        # Build a form for validation
        RealPathForm = self.get_form_class()
        form = RealPathForm(path_form_data, { 'file': request.FILES['files[]'] })

        if form.is_valid():
            path = form.save(commit=False)

            # Temporary workaround to load path model with derived data - shouldn't be necessary?
            for f, v in path_form_data.items():
                setattr(path, f, v)

            path.save()

            return JsonResponse({
                'success': True,
                'path_id': int(path.id),
                'form': render_to_string('RealPath_edit.html', {
                    'path': path,
                    'form': RealPathForm(
                        instance=path, prefix='path-%d' % path.id
                    ),
                }, request=request),
            })
        else:
            # Validation error
            return JsonResponse({
                'success': False,
                'error_message': '\n'.join(['\n'.join([force_str(i) for i in v]) for k, v in form.errors.items()]),
            })

    def get_edit_handler(self):
        edit_handler = self.model_admin.get_edit_handler(
            instance=self.get_instance(), request=self.request
        )
        return edit_handler.bind_to(model=self.model_admin.model)


class RealPathAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    model = RealPath
    menu_label = "Real Path"
    menu_icon = "arrow-right"
    menu_order = 320
    add_to_settings_menu = False
    exclude_from_explorer = False
    list_display = ("name", "start_timestamp", "start_location", "stop_timestamp", "stop_location")
    form_fields_exclude = ["start_timestamp", "stop_timestamp", "average_speed"]

    create_view_class = RealPathCreateView

    def get_edit_handler(self, instance, request):
        return PathFormEditHandler(())


modeladmin_register(RealPathAdmin)
```

The path files are uploading fine, and are made available in the RealPathCreateView.post() method. The file is processed to extract the relevant data, and put into `path_form_data`. My expectation is that when the form is created with `RealPathForm`, it will create an instance of the `RealPath` model and populate the fields therein with that data. What I have found is that the data values are not populated; if at this point I attempt a save with `form.save(commit=True)`, an exception is raised `django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed: paths_realpath.start_timestamp`.

Deeper investigation of the problem shows the `form` object has an empty `fields` attribute, which means the `RealPath` model fields were never being set, the form is then "validated" and the save fails because most of the data passed to the database layer were either `None` or `0.0`. The full list of fields *is* being generated in django's `ModelFormMetaclass.__new__()` method, based on the contents of the model, but never passed down to the model itself.

I eventually implemented the workaround to set the model fields manually (as in the code above), but then I found the subsequent form rendering was also broken because of the need to iterate over the form fields - which weren't populated either. Clearly I should fix the first problem as it will fix the second (and probably others), but I cannot see where in the django code this transfer occurs and hence what changes I need to make to my code.

Thanks for your assistance.

*Note: You will note that the `RealPath` model is based on an `AbstractPath` model - the reason for this is that I will have several types of real `Path`s with data derived from different sources. I've left that structure there in case it is the reason for the problem I'm experiencing.*

Answer (score 1):

I eventually came to the conclusion that if the model fields were to be set from the derived file data, and if I wanted the ModelAdmin and django form functions work, I would have to remove the `form_fields_exclude` attribute in `RealPathAdmin` - it is essentially incompatible with the NOT NULL constraints in the `RealPath` model. When subsequently editing, this results in a Form with all the data present including the fields I don't want to be editable. I could then hide those *non-editable fields* by using a `ModelAdmin.panels` attribute, specifying `HiddenInput` widgets and using a bit of CSS to completely hide them from the user.

It also meant accepting that all the data will flow out to and back from the browser, thus providing a technical opportunity to change the data that should only come from the original file. This is low-risk in my deployment scenario, but the opening could be closed with more logic in the edit view.

My revised gisted code is as follows:

models.py: (no change)

```
from django.db import models

class AbstractPath(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False, null=False)
    start_location = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=False, null=False)
    start_timestamp = models.DateTimeField(blank=False, null=False)
    stop_location = models.CharField(max_length=120, blank=False, null=False)
    stop_timestamp = models.DateTimeField(blank=False, null=False)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name

class RealPath(AbstractPath):
    average_speed = models.FloatField(blank=False, null=False)
    max_speed = models.FloatField(blank=False, null=False)
```

forms.py: (removed - didn't need the edit handlers)

admin.py:

```
from wagtail.contrib.modeladmin.options import ModelAdmin, modeladmin_register
from .models import RealPath
from .views import RealPathCreateView

class RealPathAdmin(ModelAdmin):
    model = RealPath
    menu_label = "Real Path"
    menu_icon = "arrow-right"
    menu_order = 320
    add_to_settings_menu = False
    exclude_from_explorer = False
    list_display = ("name", "start_timestamp", "start_location", "stop_timestamp", "stop_location")

    create_view_class = RealPathCreateView

    panels = [
        MultiFieldPanel([
            FieldPanel('name'),
            FieldPanel('start_location'),
            FieldPanel('stop_location'),
        ], heading="Real Path Name"),
        MultiFieldPanel([
            FieldPanel('start_timestamp', classname="realpath_admin_hidden", widget=HiddenInput),
            FieldPanel('stop_timestamp', classname="realpath_admin_hidden", widget=HiddenInput),
            FieldPanel('average_speed', classname="realpath_admin_hidden", widget=HiddenInput),
            FieldPanel('max_speed', classname="realpath_admin_hidden", widget=HiddenInput),
        ])
    ]


modeladmin_register(RealPathAdmin)
```

views.py: (view class moved from admin.py)

```
from wagtail.contrib.modeladmin.views import CreateView

from django.template.loader import render_to_string
from django.http import HttpResponseBadRequest, JsonResponse
from django.utils.encoding import force_str

class RealPathCreateView(CreateView):
    def get_template_names(self):
        return ['RealPath_create.html']

    def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        if not request.is_ajax():
            return HttpResponseBadRequest("Cannot POST to this view without AJAX")

        if not request.FILES:
            return HttpResponseBadRequest("Must upload a file")

        # Get dict with data derived from the file - keys align with model fields
        path_form_data = pathfile_process(request.FILES['files[]'])

        # Build a form for validation
        RealPathForm = self.get_form_class()
        form = RealPathForm(path_form_data, { })

        if form.is_valid():
            path = form.save()

            return JsonResponse({
                'success': True,
                'path_id': int(path.id),
                'form': render_to_string('RealPath_edit.html', {
                    'path': path,
                    'form': RealPathForm(
                        instance=path, prefix='path-%d' % path.id
                    ),
                }, request=request),
            })
        else:
            # Validation error
            return JsonResponse({
                'success': False,
                'error_message': '\n'.join(['\n'.join([force_str(i) for i in v]) for k, v in form.errors.items()]),
            })
```